# Will / Going to

Tags: grammar, differences, future, will-be-going

I'm having some troubles with the usage of **will** and **going to** in the future tense.
I have searched this problem all over Google, but I can't seem to find the universal explanation (for example, one site says things 1 and 2, another site says things 2, 3 and 4, the third site says only things 2 and 3 etc.). I will be very grateful if somebody answers my question briefly and clearly, like this:

**WILL**
Usage 1 - 
Usage 2 - 
Usage 3 - 
...
Example 1 - 
Example 2 - 
Example 3 - 
...

**GOING TO**
Usage 1 - 
Usage 2 -
Usage 3 -
...
Example 1 - 
Example 2 -
Example 3 -
...

**Also**, have a look at the following sentence

> Newspapers probably **won't be used** in the future because the Internet is slowly taking over.
>   OR
>   Newspapers probably **aren't going to be used** in the future because the Internet is slowly taking over

I feel like it should be ''won't be used''. I'm having doubts because it has ''probably'' (which they taught us indicates a prediction so we should use ''will'') and ''because the Internet is slowly taking over'' (which they taught us indicates connection to the future, clear evidence by which we can judge and use ''going to'').
I hope I'm not asking for too much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally, _be going to_ (pronounced /ṃɡənə, zɡənə, ṛɡənə, wzɡənə, wṛɡənə/, depending on the subject pronoun) is used when something is imminent, and _will_ when it's somewhat farther in the future, but certain. On a hiking trail, the only correct thing to say is _Look out! That rock is going to fall!_ Saying _That rock will fall_ is a prediction for sometime, but probly not now. Of course, if you said _That rock is to fall_ you'd be saying it was on the schedule for a certain time.

Comment: @JohnLawler Another option would be *That rock is about to fall!*

Comment: Right. There are always lots of options in English.

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html has a decent summary. However, take into consideration that sometimes *will*; going to, and *present continuous*, can be interchangeable: *Tomorrow I'm leaving*; "*Tomorrow I'm going to leave" and *"Tomorrow I will leave"* all mean pretty much the same.

Comment: Thank you all.
I have edited the question, please re-read.

Comment: It's a pity you didn't make the edit sooner, your question now needs five votes before it can be reopened. The first one will be mine, but it **won't** be enough.

Answer (score -1):

> I will go to school tomorrow.
>
> I am going to school tomorrow.
>
> I will be going to school tomorrow.
>
> I am going to go to school tomorrow.
>
> I am going to be going to school tomorrow.

"Going" is interesting, as it can both be the future tense conjugation of "to go (somewhere)", but also as a abstract future indication of action.

> I am going to lie down.
> I am going to go to bed to lie down.

English is confusing.